# Specs for the 54622D oscilloscope expansion bus

Tags: oscilloscope, bus

Just bought a used HP/Agilent/Keysight 54622D oscilloscope. There is an expansion bus connector on the back. I've been looking around for the specs on the bus such as connector type, electrical specification, and interfacing protocol, but have come up empty.  Anyone have references?

Comment: Is it this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-488 ?

Comment: No, it is not a GPIB (or HPIB to us oldtimers).  There is an expansion bus to GPIB module that can be attached.  The expansion bus must have a parallel out architecture, which was intriguing for me, as I'm considering some tinkering.